# Android ListView trouble with loading image and info from database

Tags: android, image, url, android-listview, android-bitmap

I'm trying to create something like messaging app. I have listview where has to be user image, name and his message. With message i have no problem, because i download them before listview creation. But with image is a big trouble. Listview item loads faster than image, so in reault i get listview with message text, but without image. I'm just out of ideas. Looking forward for your solutions.

Comment: please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

you should load images in another thread(background) like using handler,asynck task

or use libraries like universal image loader

refer [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

Comment: Yea. I know. And do like that. But ui thread runs faster than thread, where image is loading. So finally i have listview items without image that has to be downloaded

Comment: But i need there to be image i want, not  default

Comment: From network. I'm loading user's profile that includes his name and url to image

Comment: then the image load based on the internet speed so it may load fast or not. because you first show the loading view of image

Comment: I don't understand a bit. What should i do?